# Where to find the viewport meta tag on Magento?

Tags: magento

Actually I need to make an magento site non-responsive, I'm trying to find the viewport meta tag in head file but it's not there. Please let me know where can I find this?

Answer (score 4):

Please check this file.
\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\head.phtml

But if you are using the custom theme, you must find out that file in your theme.
So like this :

\app\design\frontend\default[Your theme]\template\page\html\head.phtml

Comment: I found it in - app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml       I removed it from this file and mentioned it in -app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/head.phtml        It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Override or create file in theme and add below code in your theme

> /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

to

> /app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

and add your viewport tag in  section

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <!-- your meta viewport -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  </head>
</page>
```

**this will update your default magento tag**